# AIX vg creation problem in shell script

Tags: shell, aix, volume

Creating a volume group using `mkvg -y trialvg xyz` works but
the same line represented like this `mkvg -y $vg_name $dev_name` in a shell script
causes the following problem :

bash-4.0# ./execute_AIX.sh
Creating VG trialvg with device xyz
Executing Command: mkvg -y trialvg xyz
0519-100 libodm: Cannot open the object class collection file.
        Check path name and permissions.
0516-307 mkvg: Unable to access Device Configuration
        Database.
Creating VG: Failed

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of ./execute_AIX.sh

Answer (score 1):

Somebody must have set the `maxdata` environment variable. That causes this error.
This has something to do with the max `#` of shared memory segment that a process can attach to (shmat problem).

So do `export LDR_CNTRL=MAXDATA=0x80000000@DSA` and try again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

In maxdata=0x80000000 setting, only segment b and c will be available for shmat (after 8 segments are allocated for user heap) and one more shmat request will fail as segment e is already attached.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `set -x` in the script to see what commands get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your clue is in a portion of the error message: "Check path name and permissions."

There is something different between the environment of your script and your interactive environment. Two likely candidates are a missing shebang (or one that specifies a different shell) or a `PATH` that differs. Without seeing the script it's difficult to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you ODMDIR environment variable (env |grep ODMDIR). This should point to "/etc/objrepos".